# open multiple forms with main form

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have 5 forms:

```
Form 1
Form 2
From 3
Form 4
Form 5
```

Main form is “Form A”. All forms' buttons are pasted on “form A”.

Is it possible that I open all forms at same time and all are active for data input and other are minimized? All forms are developed in 6i.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to "open" another form, by using the following built-ins:

- `CALL_FORM` will run the indicated form and keep the parent form active
- `OPEN_FORM` opens the indicated form; it is used to crate multiple-form application (i.e. the one that opens more than one form at the same time)
- `NEW_FORM` exits the current form and runs the indicated form.

These are well described in Forms' Online Help system (navigate to "Help", perform search and read what's written in there). Then pick the option which suits you best.